# Wordpress get_footer() is calling default footer, not the one I call

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit new to this, but I researched this topic a bit online and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. So basically, I created a duplicate footer to call for the homepage. We use a marketing automation tool called Pardot and we don't want to track visits to the homepage. So I created a file in the footer folder next to "footer-default.php" called "footer-nopardot.php" that omits the code.

In the home.php file, I edit the bottom with

```
<?php

get_footer('nopardot'); ?>
```

But it appears the homepage is still calling the default footer. Any advice on what to do or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `footer-` is added to your footer-filename?

Comment: Since you are wanting to exclude a piece of code, have you thought about using an if statement instead? Where if it's the homepage then the code won't display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to your home template:

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) :
        get_footer( 'nopardot' );
    else :
        get_footer();
    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this just isn't working. The file is saved in the footer folder as footer-nopardot.php. The other file in the folder is footer-default.php. I removed the code I wanted omitted from footer-nopardot.php and put the exact code you posted at the bottom of the home.php file. But it's still pulling the default footer. Is there a problem with where the footer-default.php is saved?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! Apparently there was a footer-default.php file and a footer.php file. I just added the -nopardot one next to the simple footer.php. and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this loop just replace the home or 404 by your page name where you want to display your footer:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_footer( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_footer( '404' );
else :
    get_footer();
endif;
?>
```

and since you are just changing your home page footer u can just do this

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) :
        get_footer( 'yourName' );
    else :
        get_footer();
    endif;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the file name to be `footer-yourName.php`
and then call it as follow:

```
get_footer( 'yourName' );
```

hope that helps :)